# How do I choose proper diodes for a 74HC595 shift register with a wired OR connection?

Tags: shift-register, input, components, digital-in

I want to use a [wired OR connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection#The_wired_OR_connection) to connect some pins of the 74HC595 shift register to an Arduino Digital Input Pin. How do I choose proper diodes for this situation?

- Maximum rated forward current has to be higher than whatever current a single pin of the 74HC595 produces.
- The `V_F` forward voltage drop has to be as low as possible to make sure that a HIGH from the shift register has still a voltage high enough to result in a HIGH at the Arduino pin after passing through the diode.
- Switching time has to be low enough to match the shift register's frequency.

So far, so good? What did I miss?

By the way, I haven't decided on the voltage for `VCC`, yet. Most likely, either `5 V` or `3.3 V`.

[image: schematic]

Comment: **Why??** Your "requirements" are contradictory; RTL went out of vogue in the early 1960s precisely because it was slow (among other problems). You have not specified the frequency, but it is unlikely to be so high that you need to worry. This also is not an Arduino question?

Comment: @Milliways Thank you for your comment. :-) You seem really taken aback by my question. I'm just getting started with electronics and Arduino, so it's fairly probable that I'm approaching something the completely wrong way. With RTL, do you mean Register-transfer_level? I'm having problems understanding the correlation. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: Concerning the relevance towards Arduino, I was thinking that the microcontroller on hand plays a part in choosing the proper diode. Despite the diode's voltage drop, I still have to reach the HIGH logic level for exactly this microcontroller. Isn't this dependent on which microcontroller is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, almost any diode will work.  Searching, it turns out that the [1N4148](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N4148_signal_diode) is a popular ubiquitous choice.  But don't go out of your way to obtain this particular diode.

> Maximum rated forward current has to be higher than whatever current a
>   single pin of the 74HC595 produces.

You should turn your thinking around.  Consider the nominal high voltage of the 74HC595, subtract the forward bias diode voltage drop (usually  0.7V for a silicon diode) and divide that by the resistor you pick.  That will be the current passing out of the 74HC595, through the diode and resistor.  Only a small amount of current will pass into the Arduino.  It should be negligible for most applications.  You should pick a resistor high enough to only allow milliamps of current to pass through this circuit.

> The V_F forward voltage drop has to be as low as possible to make sure
>   that a HIGH from the shift register has still a voltage high enough to
>   result in a HIGH at the Arduino pin after passing through the diode.

Check the voltage margin allow for a logical high input to the Arduino (Atmel processor).  I think 3V - 0.7V = 2.3V is still considered a logical high.  However, if you think this is too close, then switch to the 5 volt Arduino where the 0.7 volt drop will make less difference.

> Switching time has to be low enough to match the shift register's
>   frequency.

I doubt this will be a problem.  That is, I doubt the CMOS logic will surpass the speed at which the diode can turn on / off.

Comment: Isn't there a very short period of time, when a diode in front of a former HIGH pin (now LOW) is still conducting and now allows for a short into this now LOW pin?

Comment: There might be.  But I believe it will not be noticeable relative to the time it takes for a CMOS device to charge up and start conducting or discharge and stop conducting.  Almost all logic chips use CMOS like technology these days.

Comment: Aah, I might be getting somewhere now. You're saying the shift register needs some time to switch from LOW to HIGH as well - and this time is enough time for the diode to switch to reverse biased?

Comment: That almost right.   A computer designer is interested in something called propagation delay.  Every "gate" (which is made up of transistors and in some cases diodes) contribute to the over all propagation delay.  There are dozens of gates in the shift register.  So there is significant delay between the shift register's clock input changing and the shift register's outputs changing.  The software program you write for the Arduino and hard ware you are designing will have to work in harmony to pull this off.  Adding diodes as you have done will add an insignificant amount of propagation delay.

Comment: After reading about propagation delay, this seems important to explain that the additional diode won't "affect the signal". (So thank you very much for introducing me to this technical term!) However, I feel terrible for suggesting this, because your answer helped me so much already - is it possible you misunderstood my follow-up question? There is a short period of time which the diode needs to switch from forward bias to reverse bias. Isn't it possible, that current flows through this still forward biased diode (during its switching time) into the (now LOW) output pin, and harm the IC?

Comment: You are now asking questions that are dealt with in introductory college level logic classes.  I can not imagine how including a Wired Or Gate using diodes and a properly selected resistor can cause damage.  Nor can I image how the diode switching bias delay is significant with respect to charging the capacitance load naturally found at the input of CMOS based logic chips and processors. As such you may ask why the circuit you added is not more common.  Power consumption.  When any of the shift register's outputs are high, a current flows through the resistor and that power is wasted as heat.

Comment: "Only a small amount of current will pass into the Arduino. " Yes, only 1uA max per the datasheet.

Comment: That is not the current that is wasting power.  The current that is wasting power occurs when any of the shift register output pins are pulled high.  Then the current flows through the diode connected to that pin and through the resistor to ground.  That said, you can reduce power loss by choosing a larger resistance.  But a larger resistance will allow more noise which can affect the input to the Arduino in unexpected ways.

Comment: I should add that the amount of current (likely a couple of mA) we are talking about here doesn't make all the much different in a plug in project.  But it starts to affect battery life a in portable project.